# Is there a convenient way to update stubbed API calls when the app is updated to expect a new JSON format?

Tags: cypress, stub, datacontract, cypress-intercept

Our app is under heavy development, and our API JSON formats are constantly changing. Here's a simplified example:

```
{
    "succeeded": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": {
        "purchaseOrderId": "1f7968e2-f18e-417b-9e7b-1c35e5bdd465",
        "vendor": {
            "vendorId": "7a76533d-9c8b-4ac0-85c0-df89eaa3cb0e",
            "name": "Owens Brothers",
            "number": "VND-8888"
        },
        "purchaseOrderNumber": 101
    },
    "errors": null
};
```

But then we learn we need to include additional info:

```
{
    "succeeded": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": {
        "purchaseOrderId": "1f7968e2-f18e-417b-9e7b-1c35e5bdd465",
        "vendor": {
            "vendorId": "7a76533d-9c8b-4ac0-85c0-df89eaa3cb0e",
            "name": "Owens Brothers",
            "number": "VND-8888"
        },
        "buyer": {
            "buyerId": "629f21c0-c27b-42d7-9a3e-bb5f9d7a268a",
            "fullName": "Allen Armstrong"
        },
        "purchaseOrderNumber": 101
    },
    "errors": null
};
```

Obviously this "breaks" the test. The frontend expects the new format, but gets the old format from my stubbed API call.

When this happens, I usually go to the live app, put it into a state that correctly populates the stuff I want to test, and use the Chrome inspect tool to get the contents of the response.

Then I sometimes edit it to make it exactly what I want and paste it into my cypress stub function.

Is there a better workflow for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to update the fixture with the `buyer` branch whilst retaining values already mocked (for example `purchaseOrderId` value), you can use lodash `merge()`.

```js
it('updates a fixture with new structure', () => {

  const currentFixture = {
    data: {
      purchaseOrderId: 'mock-this-value',    // mock is providing this value
      vendor: {
        vendorId: '7a76533d-9c8b-4ac0-85c0-df89eaa3cb0e',
      },
      purchaseOrderNumber: 101,
    },
  }

  const newStructure = {
    data: {
      purchaseOrderId: '1f7968e2-f18e-417b-9e7b-1c35e5bdd465',
      vendor: {
        vendorId: '7a76533d-9c8b-4ac0-85c0-df89eaa3cb0e',
      },
      buyer: {                             
        buyerId: '629f21c0-c27b-42d7-9a3e-bb5f9d7a268a',
      },
      purchaseOrderNumber: 101,
    },
  }

  const revisedFixture = Cypress._.merge(newStructure, currentFixture)

  // Does revised fixture have the new struture?
  expect(revisedFixture.data).to.have.property('buyer')                 // passes

  // Is the mocked value still present?
  expect(revisedFixture.data.purchaseOrderId).to.eq('mock-this-value')  // passes
})
```

To do so automatically in the test, you will need to let the `intercept` query the server.

This is an approximate, obviously you will need to tweak for your app's data (JSON parse, etc)

```js
cy.fixture(fixtureName).then(fixture => {
  cy.intercept(url, (req) => {
    req.continue().then(res => {
      const revisedFixture = Cypress._.merge(res, fixture) 
      res.send(revisedFixture)
    })
  })
})
```